# LoC (lines of code) metrics for .NET 2.0 c# projects

Tags: c#, metrics, lines-of-code

Please suggest some free tools which will help me to get Lines-of-Code metrics for C# projects using the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the LoC using [Ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Comment: It's not free, though - actually quite pricey.

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for a similar tool.
Found [Microsoft Line of Code (LOC) Counter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LOCCounter)
Its pretty good.
Feature list from code.msdn page

Features:

- Get Latest LOC Count and Code Churn by connecting to source repository
  such as VSTF, VSS , and File System
- 16 types of count (latest, Code churn with dates, labels, changesets,
  etc.,)
- Customize counting standard to suit your own environment - Add, remove
  programming languages, set
  inclusion/exclusion rules
- Report results by File, Folder, Language, Excluded LOC, and more
- Predict System Defect Density by applying Microsoft Research on the
  Code churn data
- Support for Personal Software Process(SM) / Team Software
  Process(SM) object level code churn
- Install either as Windows (XP/Vista, 32bit/64bit) Application
  or as an add-in to Visual Studio 2005
  IDE
- Save source code selections of a task and run them repeatedly
- Export results to Excel or PDF